# How to use the result of child_process spawn in a request (getting ENOENT)

Tags: node.js, request, child-process, spawn

I get an ENOENT when executing the js file containing the exact code below. And I don't know how to fix this.

Any explanation or advice is welcome but I would prefer a solution for the way I'm trying to do it. (Except if I'm doing something really stupid of course)

I have written this fake request function for testing purpose:

```
(function imaginaryRequest(req, res)
{
  getDiskInfo('/dev/simfs', info =>
  {
    console.log(info.ratio)
  })
}())
```

It is supposed to use the `getDiskInfo` function that uses child_process.spawn to get the `df -Ph` output and store it into an object.

```
/**
 * Get information on the disk space of the specified File system
 * @param {string} sysFile (ex: /dev/sda)
 * @param {function} callback
 * @return {object} df -Ph output stored into object
 */
function getDiskInfo(sysFile, callback) {

  const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
  const df_Ph = spawn("df -Ph | grep " + sysFile);

  df_Ph.stdout.on('data', data => {
    let info = data
      .split(' ')
      .filter(el => el != '')

    callback({
      maxSpace: info[1],
      used: info[2],
      unused: info[3],
      ratio: info[4],
    })
  })

  df_Ph.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  df_Ph.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
}
```

And here is the error I get in the shell:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn df -Ph | grep /dev/simfs ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, arguments to your spawned process must be passed in an array as the second argument to [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). You are getting ENOENT, because spawn is looking for a command called `df -Ph | grep /dev/simfs`, not `df`. You also can't use a pipe in spawn (since a pipe is not an argument to a process). That is a feature of a shell, so one way to do what you want would be to spawn a shell instead:

```
const df_Ph = spawn("sh", ["-c", "df -Ph | grep " + sysFile]);
```

Another is to spawn `df -Ph` and `grep` separately and pipe the first processes stdout to the stdin of the grep process. I believe that to be the better option, although it is slightly more code, it avoids spawning an unnecessary `sh` process and is more readable IMO. It would look something like this:

```
const df = spawn('df', ['-Ph']);                                                                                                                                                                                   
const grep = spawn('grep', [sysFile], { stdio: [df.stdout, 'pipe', 'pipe'] } );

grep.stdout.on( 'data', data => {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With the first solution, I get a buffer, and thus `.split()` does not work. I need to cast it to a string I guess.

Comment: @RomainVincent That's expected, you'll get a buffer either way. You can use `data.toString( )` to convert that buffer to a string.